# Failing to change the argument value using bytebuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy, javaagents

I am trying to add query params to request url using bytebuddy
here is my code:

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
    .disableClassFormatChanges()
    .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
    .type(hasSuperType(named("org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate")))
    .transform(new Transformer.ForAdvice().include(MyByteBuddy.class.getClassLoader())
    .advice(ElementMatchers.named("execute"), "agent.RestTemplateAdvice"))
    .installOn(instrumentation);
```

and advice is

```
@Advice.OnMethodEnter
public static void before(@Advice.AllArguments Object[] args) {
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!");
    String data = args[0].toString();
    data = (data + "asdgb?param=myparam");
    System.out.println(data);
    args[0] = (Object)data;
    System.out.println(args[0]);
}
```

output I am getting is

```
!!!!!!!!!!!
http://localhost:8086/movies/5678asdgb?param=myparam
http://localhost:8086/movies/5678
```

I have tried below advice too but this one is not even capturing the method call.

```
@Advice.OnMethodEnter
public static void before(@Advice.Argument(0) String argument) {
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!");
    argument = (argument + "asdgb?param=myparam");
    System.out.println(argument);
}
```

Comment: How about also showing the target class + method you want to transform? Looking at the [`RestTemplate` javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html), there are three `execute` methods, but only two of them have a `String` as first parameter, the third one has a `URI`. Maybe you call that one, which is why the advice does not match. But I am only speculating for now because I do not see the target class and how it is called.

Comment: thanks @kriegaex. I am able to solve this. After doing google search. Right way to do it is @Advice.Argument(value = 0, typing = Typing.DYNAMIC, readOnly = false) String argument.
after setting this I am able to change the parameter value.

Comment: Yeah, maybe, but still your code would not run for the `execute` method with the `URI` as first parameter because you change the first argument to always be a `String`. So your solution is not stable. either limit the method signature in your matcher or extend your advice to handle the `URI` case correctly. This is just a hacky solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, in order to change the argument you need `readOnly = false`. But like I said, your advice does not cover all three `execute()` methods. You would get class cast exceptions for the one taking an `URI` as a first parameter. Here is how to fix it:

**Helper classes to make your sample code compile:**

```java
public class MyByteBuddy {}
```

```java
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class MyRestTemplate extends RestTemplate {}
```

**ByteBuddy advice:**

```java
import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import static net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.assign.Assigner.Typing.DYNAMIC;

public class RestTemplateAdvice {
  @Advice.OnMethodEnter()
  public static void before(
    @Advice.Argument(value = 0, typing = DYNAMIC, readOnly = false) Object url
  )
    throws URISyntaxException
  {
    String newURL = url.toString() + "search?q=scrum";
    url = url instanceof URI ? new URI(newURL) : newURL;
    System.out.println(url);
  }
}
```

**Driver application:**

```java
import net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent;
import net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException;

import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.hasSuperType;
import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.named;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.GET;

class BBChangeRestTemplateReturnValue_64257928 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
    applyAdvice();
    performSampleRequests();
  }

  private static void applyAdvice() {
    Instrumentation instrumentation = ByteBuddyAgent.install();
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
      .disableClassFormatChanges()
      .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
      .type(hasSuperType(named("org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate")))
      .transform(
        new AgentBuilder.Transformer.ForAdvice()
          .include(MyByteBuddy.class.getClassLoader())
          .advice(named("execute"), "RestTemplateAdvice")
      )
      .installOn(instrumentation);
  }

  private static void performSampleRequests() throws URISyntaxException {
    try {
      new MyRestTemplate().execute("https://www.google.com/", GET, null, null);
    }
    catch (HttpClientErrorException ignored) {}
    try {
      new MyRestTemplate().execute(new URI("https://www.google.com/"), GET, null, null);
    }
    catch (HttpClientErrorException ignored) {}
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=scrum
https://www.google.com/search?q=scrum
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem when using `@AllArguments` is that you are assigning a value as such

```
args[0] = (Object) data;
```

This does not help in terms of Byte Buddy's templating capabilities. In effect, this means that you are reading all arguments into an array, assigning `data` to the first index of that array and then never use it again. Instead, you would need to:

```
Object[] _args = args;
_args[0] = (Object) data;
args = _args;
```

While this does not seem to make sense in Java code, it translates into the byte code you want where all arguments are assigned the values of the supplied array. It would however be much more efficient to do what *kriegaex* suggests to use index base proxies for arguments.

Comment: Good catch! I did not check the first code snippet, concentrating on the `@Argument(0)` variant. But I do remember how you helped me when a few months ago I stepped into the same trap with `@AllArguments`, not knowing about the counter-intuitive necessity to re-assign. I am still using that in several BB advices in Sarek, eg. [here](https://github.com/SarekTest/Sarek/blob/66c256e69ac5e7d8730e13978a3f716a96faae15/sarek-aspect/src/main/java/dev/sarek/agent/aspect/InstanceMethodAspect.java#L41). My source code comment even links back to our discussion about this, so I do not forget about it. 